# python itertools: Using cycle with islice

Tags: python, python-itertools

Question:

I have the code below. I want to know why does it not matter whether or not I include the line with the comment in the code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from itertools import *
import time
cc = cycle([ iter([1,2,3]), iter([4]) , iter([5,6]) ] )
p = 3
while p:
    try:
        for k in cc:
            print k.next()
    except StopIteration:
        p = p - 1
        cc = cycle(islice(cc,  p))  # this does not matter
```

Output:

```
1
4
5
2
6
3
```

Also checkout `roundrobin` recipe at

http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html

This code shows that `islice` is impacting `cc`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from itertools import *
import time
cc = cycle([ iter([1,2,3]), iter([4]) , iter([5,6]) ] )
p = 3
while p:
    try:
        for k in cc:
            print k,k.next()
    except StopIteration:
            print "stop iter"
            p = p - 1
            cc = cycle(islice(cc,  p))
```

Output

```
<listiterator object at 0x7f32bc50cfd0> 1
<listiterator object at 0x7f32bc518050> 4
<listiterator object at 0x7f32bc518090> 5
<listiterator object at 0x7f32bc50cfd0> 2
<listiterator object at 0x7f32bc518050> stop iter
<listiterator object at 0x7f32bc518090> 6
<listiterator object at 0x7f32bc50cfd0> 3
<listiterator object at 0x7f32bc518090> stop iter
<listiterator object at 0x7f32bc50cfd0> stop iter
```

Comment: Why do you think it should matter?  After 1, 4, 5, 2 `StopIteration` is raised, and with that line you're telling it to take the next p=2 items from cc.  But only 2 items remain, so that's the same as letting it run to the end (i.e., the same as not resetting `cc`).

Comment: @TimPeters That's not right, only two iterators do not remain, all three do. One of them is empty.

Comment: Didn't say iterators, said items:  only 6 and 3 remain.  `islice` works on the sequence of items generated, not on the internal structure of the iterator being sliced.

Comment: BTW, the `roundrobin` recipe also works fine if you comment out the corresponding line in it - try it!

Comment: Here's an example where it **does** make a difference:  change to `cycle([iter([1,2,3]), iter([4]), iter([5,6]), iter([7, 8, 9, 10])])`  This is trickier than I first thought ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters `islice` is impacting cc. Checkout my another example code.

Comment: @abc What do you mean *impacting*?

Comment: @TimPeters It slices off an iterator from cc.

Comment: @abc, agreed - and it should ;-)  Did you see the example I gave where it **does** make a difference?  Too involved to explain it in a comment.  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well... it looks like it's doing what is expected here.

So, normally, cycle works like this:

```
cycle([1,2,3,4,5]) -> [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
```

It's going to store off values until it gets a StopIterator, and then it's going to start returning values from its saved list. In this case, that's going to be `[iter(a), iter(b), iter(c)]` (where iter(x) is a listiterator object itself, across whatever is inside). So chain is actually returning something like this:

```
[iter(a), iter(b), iter(c), iter(a), iter(b), iter(c), iter(a), iter(b), iter(c), ...]
```

What looks looks like when you run it:

```
[1, 4, 5, 2, StopIterator]
```

But that's the value of k.next(), not k. the cc itself is not returning the StopIterator, the object it returns is.

Now, you call `islice(cc,2)`. This should return the sequence `[iter(c), iter(a)]`, as those are the next two items in the sequence. Again, you want cc to cycle them, but now you should get

```
[iter(c), iter(a), iter(c), iter(a), iter(c), iter(a), ...]
```

You won't notice much of a difference yet, but that's because your slice is less than the length of the original. In other words, the original would have gone
    [iter(c), iter(a), iter(b), iter(c), iter(a), ...]

but you have to go farther than two items to see that difference, and...

You start pulling items off and you get

```
[6, 3, StopIterator]
```

Only two items, so they are the same two items you'd get without the islice.

Now, when you do the `islice(cc, 2)`, you get the next two items which are `[iter(a), iter(c)]`. Both of these are exhausted, so you get

```
[StopIterator]
```

and your exact sequence.

I don't know what you are expecting, but this works exactly as i would expect it to.

Answer (score 4):

Short course:  the behaviors with and without rebinding `cc` aren't **generally** the same, but the outputs **happen** to be the same for the specific input you used.

Long course:  let's call your three iterators A, B and C.

Without the `cc` rebinding:  A produces 1, B produces 4, C produces 5, A produces 2, B raises `StopIteration`.  `p` drops to 2.  Then C produces 6, A produces 3, and B raises `StopIteration` **again**.  `p` drops to 1.  C raises `StopIteration`.  `p` drops to 0, and the loop exits.

With the `cc` rebinding:  A produces 1, B produces 4, C produces 5, A produces 2, B raises `StopIteration`.  `p` drops to 2.  All the same so far.  The purpose of the rebinding in the round-robin algorithm is to **remove** exhausted iterators.  It so happens that in this specific example it makes no difference to the outcome.  With the rebinding `islice(cc, 2)` takes "the next two things" from `cc`, which are, in order, C and A.  B is no longer there.  Then C and A are put in a new `cycle`.

Then C produces 6, A produces 3, and C raises `StopIteration`.  `p` drops to 1.  The `cc` rebinding gets rid of C (the exhausted iterator), leaving just A in a new `cycle`.  The loop goes around, and A raises `StopIteration`.  `p` drops to 0, and we're done.

Of course removing exhausted iterators is crucial to making round-robin work correctly in general.  But, as you've shown, there are specific cases in which that doesn't matter :-)

### Simple example

A simple case where rebinding `cc` makes a huge difference:

```
cc = cycle([iter([1,2,3,4,5]), iter([])])
p = 2
```

With rebinding, we get all 5 values.  Without rebinding, we only get 1 and 2.